# Brick indentation modeling

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

I'm new to blender and just want to know if there is a modifier or technique in edit mode that gives a kind of brick wall indentation. You know, the space between the bricks.

Comment: Your title asks about a texture but you seem to be talking about modelling? You can use the [edit] link below your question to update the question with additional information.

Comment: It all depends on the level of detail and realism you are trying to achieve as well as the amount of geometry you want do deal with. Do a search for bump mapping techniques or displacement maps.

Comment: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/pbr-shader-tutorial-pt1/